# Show All images on Jsp with name and size

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts2

requirement : I want to show details of image(imageName,imagesize,image) on jsp page. Image is stored in database with object type blob. Column of database tables are imageName(varchar2),imageSize(number),image(blob). There is a button in Jsp 'Show Images'. On clicking on this I have to show all the images in database table with image name and image size in tabular format.
summary : On clicking of show images I have to show all the images with image name, which are stored in db.

technology : struts2,jsp,jdbc

what i have done : I am able to see image on jsp but not able to show image name and size

BlobRetrieval.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Blob"%>
<%@page import="java.io.OutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Esp Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showImage()
        {
            document.imgFrm.action="step1Image";
            document.imgFrm.submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>       
    <s:form name="imgFrm">
        <input type="button" name="b" value="ShowImage" onclick="showImage()"/>
    <% System.out.println("[BlobRetrieval.jsp] session value "+session.getAttribute("imageRetrieved")+" if null then dont show images");%>
        <%
        if(session.getAttribute("imageRetrieved")!=null)
         {
       %>
       <br></br>
       <table id="myDiv" name="myDiv" style="color: #0900C4; font: Helvetica 12pt;border: 1px solid black; height: auto;">
           <tr>
               <td>Image name</td>
               <td> <img src="DisplayBlob.jsp"> </img></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
        <%
        }
   else
   {
System.out.println("[BlobRetrieval.jsp]Session value is null");
   }
 %> 
     </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

DisplayBlob.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>

<% Blob image = null;

java.sql.Connection con = null;

byte[ ] imgData = null ;

java.sql.Statement stmt = null;

java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;

try {



  con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:sid","schemaName", "password");

stmt = con.createStatement();

rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT fileobj,fileName,fileSize FROM DISPLAYBLOB");

if (rs.next()) {

image = rs.getBlob(1);

imgData = image.getBytes(1,(int)image.length());

} else {

out.println("Display Blob Example");

out.println("image not found for given id>");

return;

}

// display the image

response.setContentType("image/gif");

OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();

o.write(imgData);

o.flush();

o.close();
} catch (Exception e) {

out.println("Unable To Display image");

out.println("Image Display Error=" + e.getMessage());

return;

} finally {

try {

rs.close();

stmt.close();

con.close();

} catch (SQLException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

}

%>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
 <struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="struts2" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="*Image" class="example.DisplayBlob" method="{1}">
        <result name="input">BlobRetrieval.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/*.servlet"/>
 </struts>
```

DisplayBlob.java

```
package example;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
public class DisplayBlob extends ActionSupport {
public String step() throws Exception
{
    Map session = (Map)ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    session.clear();
    System.out.print("[DisplayBlob] step ");
    return "input";
}
 public String step1() throws Exception
{
    Map session = (Map)ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
    System.out.print("[DisplayBlob] step1 ");
    session.put("imageRetrieved", "imageRetrieved");
    return "input";
}
}
```

First i am accessing url ip:port/contextRoot/stepImage
On accessing this url i am calling step furntion of 'DisplayBlob.java' which is forwarding control to BlobRetrieval.jsp,then on clicking button 'show images' i am calling function of step1 of 'Displayblob.java' which is again forwarding control to 'BlobRetrieval.jsp'. Since at this time 'imageRetrieved' value is set in session so control is going in the if loop. In if loop i am showing image using image src tag but not able to show other field 'image name' and 'image size'. What if there are more than one image stored in db. Then how my code shall look like?
I am not able to think how imagename shall come from db? Without any event(user invervaention) how i shall show all imageNames with images.

Answer (score 2):

Few things which i want to mention here is that though the way you have coded the work will solve your issue but in future the code changes are maintenance will really going to be a nightmare.

Regardiing your problem i suggest you to create a DTO/bean with property you need to show in the UI

```
public class ImageBean{
 private String imageName;
 private int imageSize
  // any other field you want to
  //there getter and setters

}
```

I strongly suggest you to move out the database connectivity code from your JSP code and move it to a class say `ConnectionManager` which should be responsible to create/establish connection with Database.
Create other class which should execute your SQL query and will give you results in the javalist

In you action class call that class which will return list of all images stored in your database as a list and you can send that list back to the JSP something like

```
public class ShowImageAction extends ActionSupport{

  private List<ImageBean> imageList;
  // getter setters for this

  public String showAllImages() throws Exception{
        imageList=ConnectionManager.getConnection.executeQuery("fetch all images from DB");    
  }
}
```

In you JSP when user click on the show all images button you need to call `showAllImages` method of `ShowImageAction`. Use an iterator in the JSP to show all images being fetched from the DB

```
 <s:iterator value="imageList" status="imgObject">
    <s:property value="imageName" />
    <s:property value="imageSize" />
</s:iterator>
```

For showing the image you can store unique id of each image and when clicked can pass that id to the action and based on the id can fetch the image.

For showing image you can use Struts2 [stream result](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/stream-result.html) type like

```
 <result name="selectedImage" type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">image/jpg</param>
                <param name="inputName">imageStream</param>
                <param
name="contentDisposition">filename="image.jpg"</param>
                <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
            </result>
```

Comment: @Umesh..Thankx for reply! I shall take care all of your suggestion..."For showing the image you can store unique id of each image and when clicked can pass that id to the action and based on the id can fetch the image."There is no click, that is my problem.Without any click how can i show all images..One soltion is first i retieve all imageName and stored in ArrayList ....then iterate this aray list and then while iterating pass each imageName to databaase and retrieve blob (Again accessing database)... I am not able to understand struts2 'stream result, can you direct me any example for this?

Comment: @user752590 What specifically do you need an example of? The [stream result docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/stream-result.html) show the config. There's an example in the showcase application in the `struts-filedownload` part.